# Yeoman generator error

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

When I try to run yo app generator I get this error:

```
/Users/coder/.node/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:9229
        throw e;
              ^
Error: Cannot find module 'yeoman-generator'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/coder/.node/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/app/index.js:4:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Params:
**os** OS X Yosemite 10.10,
**yo** 1.3.3,
**node** v0.10.32

Answer (score 3):

Update npm an re-run `npm install`. There's probably been an issue during the installation process causing one module to not be installed.

Nothing else you can do about this.